# mount LVM RAID 5 with missing disk

Tags: linux, lvm, raid, raid5

I have a software RAID 5 (LVM, XFS) with three 2 TB drives.

Is it possible to mount the RAID with one missing drive (instead of having to rebuild it)? How would this be done?

[Edit]

My */etc/fstab* contains the following line that usually mounted the RAID:

> UUID=0f117576-60bb-4712-8a99-5b6b278057a8 /mnt/data xfs defaults,nofail,exec,usrquota,grpquota 0 2

After the broken hard disk was removed, it was not auto mounted any more.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
md127 : inactive sdb[2](S) sda[1](S)
      3906767024 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

this is what `dmesg` says about it

> [  473.500360] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
>
> [  473.502334] XFS (md127): SB validate failed with error 5.

and mounting it fails

```
$ mount -t xfs /dev/md127 /mnt/data
mount: /dev/md127: can't read superblock
```

Comment: `md` should handle the missing drive transparently - when you try and mount filesystems on the device in question, it should allow you to do so. What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: @mjturner I added some information what I've tried so far